# como renomear os dados de uma coluna com pandas?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas

tenho 2 datasets csv mergeados e preciso renomear os dados da coluna colocando somente a abreviação, tipo "new york" virar "NY".

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa usar `.map()`, teste o seguinte código:

```
d = {"New York": "NY", "Rio de Janeiro": "RJ"}
df[nova_coluna] = df[coluna_com_nomes_por_extenso].map(d)
# ou df[coluna_com_nomes_por_extenso] = df[coluna_com_nomes_por_extenso].map(d) 
# para renomear os valores da mesma coluna

df.head()
```

Answer (score -2):

Pandas DataFrame contém o método replace que pode ser usado para alterar dados.
confira o exemple abaixo.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Coluna1": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Rio de Janeiro"], 
                   "Coluna2": [4, 5, 6]})
print(df)
          Coluna1  Coluna2
0        New York        4
1     Los Angeles        5
2  Rio de Janeiro        6


# Alterar dados
# sintaxe é seguinte df.replace({"valor atual": "Novo Valor"})

df = df.replace({"New York": "NY"})
print(df)

          Coluna1  Coluna2
0              NY        4
1     Los Angeles        5
2  Rio de Janeiro        6
```

Comment: Mas no caso seria renomear as tabelas, e não a coluna. Tentei o seu código colocando rows no lugar de columns, mas não deu.

Comment: Nesse caso você precisar alterar dados nas céculas, já atualizei o código usando .replace.